# How to add a shortcut for preventing hibernate in Windows

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, hibernate

I want to create a shortcut or a context menu option that will prevent Windows from hibernating.

I already have the hibernate option ON, but I do not want to switch it off . I want to add a ***one-time exception*** which will prevent it from **hibernating** or sleeping.

Any command which I can make into a shortcut , a .bat file or a program which can help me in my problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can try [Insomnia](https://dlaa.me/Insomnia/) it keeps your windows awake 
 Insomnia is a simple program to disable sleep mode for as long as it's running. Closing the Insomnia window immediately returns to whatever sleep mode was in effect before it was run. Yes, it's that simple!

Comment: please add more details what the program is and what is does